# Grab username off twitter

Tags: vb.net

How can I grab the number of favorites off of a page like this? https://twitter.com/DaltonMetzler4

Like how can I grab the # of followers and number of favorites?

Comment: I'd suggest referring to the Twitter REST API. Create an HTTPClient and issue requests according to the API guidelines. https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public

Comment: Step 1) Read [Ask]  Step 2)  Pick a language  Step 3) Profit!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the Twitter REST API: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public and understand how to authenticate your application with OAuth.

Followers: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/followers/ids

Favorites: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/favorites/list

You can explore the entire API with the Twitter Console: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/tools/console

Here's a good intro/tutorial to the Twitter API: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/building-with-the-twitter-api-getting-started--cms-22192